# Как группировать по нескольким полям?

Tags: c#, datagridview, linq2sql

Пример кода взят из MSDN. В нем показано,как получить сумму ,группируя по одному полю.

```
`// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

var query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    group order by order.Field<Int32>("ContactID") into g
    select new
    {
        Category = g.Key,
        TotalDue = g.Sum(order => order.Field<decimal>("TotalDue")),
    };
`
```

Мне нужно группировать по нескольким полям . Как это можно сделать? 
Привожу свой код ,как я это использую :

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var  regi = (from r in db.Registrs.ToList()
                   group r by  r.company into g
                   //group r by r.city into f
                   select new
                  {
                       Date = checkBox1.Checked ?  g.Key : null,                           
                       Company = checkBox2.Checked ? g.Key : null,
                       City = checkBox3.Checked ? g.Key : null,                                         
                       Country = checkBox4.Checked ? g.Key : null,
                       Manager = checkBox5.Checked ? g.Key : null,
                       Quantity = checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked ? g.Sum(s => s.quantity) : null,
                       Amount = checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked ? g.Sum(s => s.amount) : null,                           
                   }).Distinct();         
        registrDataGridView.DataSource = regi.ToList();
    }
```

В комментарии показано,чего примерно я хочу добиться. В данном случае группирует только по g.company, мне же нужно сделать такую группировку по всем полям. Результат показан на скришоте.[image: Для company - правильно выводит]

[image: Для даты ,как и ожидалось - не правильно.Должно выводит дату]

Для company  - правильно выводит.
Для даты ,как и ожидалось  - не правильно.Должно выводить дату.
Так и для любых других полей - только их значения.
Если группировку не производить совсем,то неправильно считает значения quantity и amount(они должны выводиться всегда).

При группировке в  виде group r by new { r.company,r.city,r.country,r.manager } into g ,происходит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
`var  regi = (from r in db.Registrs.ToList() 
                       group r by new { r.company,r.city,r.country,r.manager } into g
                         //group r by r.city into f
                       select new
                      {
                          // Date = checkBox1.Checked ? (DateTime?) r.date  : (DateTime?)null,
                           // Company = checkBox2.Checked ? (from s in db.Registrs group s by s.company into g select g.Key) : null,
                           Company = checkBox2.Checked ? g.Key : null,
                           City = checkBox3.Checked ? g.Key : null,                                         
                            Country = checkBox4.Checked ? g.Key : null,
                            Manager = checkBox5.Checked ? g.Key : null,
                            Quantity = checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked ? g.Sum(s => s.quantity) : null,
                            Amount = checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked ? g.Sum(s => s.amount) : null,                           
                       }).Distinct();         
            registrDataGridView.DataSource = regi.ToList();`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно в формирование ключа группировки добавить условие ваших чекбоксов. Т.е. примерно так:

```
group r by new { Date=checkBox1.Checked ? r.Date:null,
                 Company=checkBox2.Checked?r.Company:null 
                 ... 
               } into g
```

При выводе таблицы, соответственно, выводить `r.Key.Date`, `r.Key.Company` и т.д.

Comment: Работает!!!Спасибо! =) 
А можно ли теперь выводить только нужные колонки, убирать пустые?

Comment: "А можно ли теперь выводить только нужные колонки, убирать пустые"- а как пользователь будет фильтр менять, если спрячете "ненужные" колонки? ;)

Comment: Нажать на fill table и заново заполнить таблицу. Такая логика :) 
Я по этой теме создала новый вопрос,чтобы не засорять комментарии.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661365/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-datagridview-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-linq

Answer (score 3):

Используйте для группировки анонимный тип, запись вида:

```
group r by new { r.company, r.city } into g
```

Для ознакомления: [Практическое руководство. Группировка результатов запросов (Руководство по программированию на C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb545971.aspx)

Comment: Так тоже пробовала. Только что дополнила вопрос,добавив результат,что происходит в случае группировки group by new{}

Comment: @SoftySh, да, все верно, вы же туда всю группу выводите, а вам нужно после `g.Key` поставить точку и выбрать что нужно. Понимаете о чем я?

Comment: Да. В таком случае значение правильное, но не считает сумму quantity и amount. Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: @SoftySh, поставьте брэйкпоинт, посмотрите, что у вас есть, да и есть ли эти значения вообще. Кстати, quantity и amount можно и в группе сразу посчитать.