# Удалить объекты с одинаковыми полями из списка

Tags: c#, linq

мне нужно удалить повторяющиеся  элементы, где два параметра равны. 
Удалось удалить элементы, где повторяется только один параметр (`Id`), вот код:

```
var items = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(group => 
            group.OrderBy(x => x.Date).First()).ToList();
```

Это список на входе:

```
Id: 1, Type: 2, Date: 12.02.2018
Id: 1, Type: 2, Date: 15.02.2018
Id: 1, Type: 1, Date: 19.02.2018
Id: 2, Type: 2, Date: 12.02.2018
```

На выходе должно получиться:

```
Id: 1, Type: 2, Date: 12.02.2018
Id: 1, Type: 1, Date: 19.02.2018
Id: 2, Type: 2, Date: 12.02.2018
```

Как правильно удалить из списка повторяющиеся элементы, где `Id` и `Type` равны?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77509/discussion-on-question-by-nikita-------).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как группировать по нескольким полям?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661342/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Comment: @0xdb ни разу не дубликат. В приведенном вами вопросе говорится о более сложном случае - группировке по динамическому списку полей. Тут же поля для группировки известны заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь анонимным классом:

```
items = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Type })
             .Select(a => a.OrderBy(x => x.Date).First())
             .ToList();
```

Или кортежем (C# 7.0+):

```
items = items.GroupBy(x => (x.Id, x.Type))
             .Select(a => a.OrderBy(x => x.Date).First())
             .ToList();
```